# ¿Como puedo mostrar los datos de un modal?

Tags: angular8, angular-material

Estoy tratando de mostrar en un modal los datos del detalle de un archivo y abro el modal mandando la id cero problema luego en el modal muestro los datos en la consola me los muestra pero no se me muestran en el HTML no se muestran
ojala puedan ayudarme
**fragmento donde llamo al modal**

```
opendialogdescarga(){
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogDescargaComponent,{
    width: '700px',
    data: {
      carga: this.id,

       }
});
dialogRef.afterClosed()
```

}

**Aca esta el componente DialogDescargaComponent.ts**

```html
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';
import { ProgressService } from 'src/app/services/service.index';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Upload } from 'src/app/models/upload.model';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog-descarga',
  templateUrl: './dialog-descarga.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog-descarga.component.css']
})
export class DialogDescargaComponent implements OnInit {
  listadescargas: Upload[];

  constructor(
    public http: HttpClient,
    public router: Router,
    public _progressService: ProgressService,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogDescargaComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let out = this._progressService.getListaDownload(this.data.carga);
    out.subscribe( function(resp){
           this.listadescargas = resp;
           console.log(resp);
    })
  
  }
  onClickOK():void{
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

En la consola del navegador muestro los valores que quiero pintar en el html pero no se me divisan en el modal acá muestro el html del modal.

```html
<div ><h2>Archivos Originales</h2></div> <br><br>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th >Nombre de archivo</th>
        <th >Peso archivo</th>
        <th >Fecha De Ingreso</th>
        <th >Descarga</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>{{listadescargas?.uploadOriginalName}}</td>
        <td>{{listadescargas?.uploadSize}}</td>
        <td>{{listadescargas?.uploadDt}}</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
    <div >
      <button (click)="onClickOK()" type="button" class="btn btn-success" > Aceptar</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

el inconveniente es que tu servicio carga los datos después de que se te abre la modal, deberías tener un observable que pueda refrescar los datos cuando la modal ya este abierta, intenta esto.

Primero agrega un debbuger en donde imprimes los datos para ver en que momento se cargan, luego en tu HTML agrega

```
{{listadescargas?.uploadOriginalName | async }}
```

El pipe async funciona como observable y estará actualizando los valores cuando terminen de cargarse.

Cuéntame como te va con la solución, un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Estás guardando los datos en una variable que se llama listadescargas y por su nombre asumo que es un arreglo por tanto hacer algo como listadescargas.uploadDt etc no funcionará, debes recorrer la lista usando ngFor y ahí si por cada item hacer item.uploadDt.
Igual sería bueno ver lo que imprimes por consola, espero que te sirva saludos